# Dissipation and symplectic manifolds

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, ode

I'm working on an API for simulation of port-Hamiltonian systems. As far as I understand it, a Hamiltonian system is symplectic if it is power conserving, and so including resistive elements would thus destroy the symplectic nature. My question is, if I add an extra state variable, the dissipated heat, along with its adjoint, does this restore its symplecticity?

Further, if I didn't include the extra state variable, would I still benefit from using symplectic integrators? And do systems lying on a contact manifold still benefit from symplectic integrators?

Comment: Could you give us a more specific operator form? Whether your addition is [symplectic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_operator) is hard to tell (for me) from your description.

Comment: @Deathbreath, I do not, other than the for every dissipative term (e.g. for a resistor in an RLC circuit), add a term to the Hamiltonian of the extra state variable, equal to the negative of the dissipative term (e.g. a virtual resistor with negative resistance)

Comment: In general, one cannot change a dissipative system to a conservative one.